# Is it possible to compare the .qm/compiled Qt translation files?

Tags: qt, qt5, translation, qtranslate

I have a Qt5 project which introduces changes to its .qm files, and I wanted to check what these differences where.  Does anyone know if it's possible to diff/compare .qm files?

Comment: qm files are binary hashes, depending on the version of the toolkit, they only contain hash and translation, not the originating text. Why would you want to compare these? They certainly depend on the toolkit used as the serialization depends on Qt structures being serialized and these formats have changed over time. Compare the ts-files instead if you have to.

Comment: I want to compare .qm files because I have commits to .qm that are not accompanied by changes to the corresponding .ts files, and I need to check what those changes are.